# Nodejs does not display the images

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I have a very simple nodejs app which is rendering a HTML page.

My directory structure:

```
C:\Users\user_id\Desktop\keys\nodejs\node-v12.13.1-win-x64
12/02/2019  05:08 PM    <DIR>          .
12/02/2019  05:08 PM    <DIR>          ..
11/19/2019  01:35 PM            54,162 CHANGELOG.md
12/02/2019  06:23 PM    <DIR>          images
12/02/2019  06:27 PM               353 index.html
10/23/2019  11:31 AM             2,953 install_tools.bat
11/19/2019  01:35 PM            78,655 LICENSE
11/19/2019  01:50 PM        28,787,352 node.exe
10/10/2019  11:31 AM               702 nodevars.bat
10/10/2019  11:31 AM            10,630 node_etw_provider.man
12/02/2019  05:06 PM    <DIR>          node_modules
10/10/2019  11:31 AM               930 npm
10/10/2019  11:31 AM               483 npm.cmd
10/10/2019  11:31 AM               922 npx
10/10/2019  11:31 AM               539 npx.cmd
11/19/2019  01:35 PM            26,931 README.md
12/02/2019  05:07 PM             1,765 server.js
              13 File(s)     28,966,377 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  108,750,237,696 bytes free
```

The html page

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Index
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>
      <p>Hello! Image
        <br><br>
          <img src="http://localhost:3000/images/img_chania.jpg" alt="Flowers in Chania" width="660" height="345">
      </p>
    </h1>
    <h1>
      Bye Bye! Image
    </h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

The server.js file

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
const port = 3000

/*
* Default route for the web app
*/
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Welcome'))

/*
* Route to render HTML Page
*/
app.get('/renderHTML', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('./index.html', {
        root: path.join(__dirname, './')
    })
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening on port ${port}!`))
```

All images are stored in the images directory.

If i simply render the index.html page the images are visible.
The images just does not show up when we run it through the node app.

It looks like an issue with the path and when debugging using inspect and click on console it gives me a 404 error.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thank you

Comment: `src="http://localhost:3000/images/img_chania.jpg"` it is incorrect. You need to give the location of image without `localhost:3000`

Comment: @stud3nt — While relative URLs are generally better, using an absolute URL is not a problem here.

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html - take a look in to this

Comment: Not related to your problem, but it seems like you are using the nodejs installation folder to keep your scripts, That is not a good idea, Use some other folder.

Comment: @Quentin Agree, the images folder has to be shared as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have a route for `/` and you have a route for `/renderHTML`.

You don't have a route for `/images` so of course it gives you a 404.

Use [the static module as described in the Getting Started guide](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html):

```
app.use("/images", express.static('images'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Static image must be served with static middleware. Check this article for detail. http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html#serving-static-files-in-express

`app.use(express.static('public'))`